# i not showing up as number in loop

Tags: r, for-loop

so I have a loop that finds the position in the matrix where there is the largest difference in consecutive elements. For example, if thematrix[8] and thematrix[9] have the largest difference between any two consecutive elements, the number given should be 8.

I made the loop in a way that it will ignore comparisons where one of the elements is NaN (because I have some of those in my data). The loop I made looks like this.

```
thenumber = 0 #will store the difference
for (i in 1:nrow(thematrix) - 1) {
  if (!is.na(thematrix[i]) & !is.na(thematrix[i + 1])) {
    if (abs(thematrix[i] - thematrix[i + 1]) > thenumber) {
      thenumber = i
    }
  }
}
```

This looks like it should work but whenever I run it

```
Error in if (!is.na(thematrix[i]) & !is.na(thematrix[i + 1])) { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

I tried this thing but with a random number in the brackets instead of i and it works. For some reason it only doesn't work when I use the i specified in the beginning of the for-loop. It doesn't recognize that i represents a number. Why doesn't R recognize i?

Also, if there's a better way to do this task I'd appreciate it greatly if you could explain it to me

Answer (score 2):

You are pretty close but when you call `i in 1:nrow(thematrix) - 1` R evaluates this to make `i = 0` which is what causes this issue. I would suggest either calling `i in 1:nrow(thematrix)` or `i in 2:nrow(thematrix) - 1` to start your loop at `i = 1`. I think your approach is generally pretty intuitive but one suggestion would be to frequently use the `print()` function to evaluate how `i` changes over the course of your function.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `:` operator has higher precedence than `-`; you just need to use parentheses around `(nrow(thematrix)-1)`. For example,

```
thematrix <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 5)
##
wrong <- 1:nrow(thematrix) - 1
right <- 1:(nrow(thematrix) - 1)
##
R> wrong
#[1] 0 1 2 3 4
R> right
#[1] 1 2 3 4
```

---

Where the error message is coming from trying to access the zero-th element of `thematrix`:

```
R> thematrix[0]
integer(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

The other two answers address your question directly, but I must say this is about the worst possible way to solve this problem in R.

```
set.seed(1)             # for reproducible example
x <- sample(1:10,10)    # numbers 1:10 in random order
x
# [1]  3  4  5  7  2  8  9  6 10  1
which.max(abs(diff(x))) 
# [1] 9
```

The `diff(...)` function calculates sequential differences, and `which.max(...)` identifies the element number of the maximum value in a vector.